# Why is ?Sized a bound for certain RefCell functions, but not all?

Tags: memory, rust

I noticed that `?Sized` is a bound on the type parameter `T` for some functions (`borrow`, `borrow_state`, and `borrow_mut`), however, it is **not** a bound for `new` or `into_inner`.  If I can't create a `RefCell` containing something that is dynamically sized (`RefCell<T : ?Sized>`), then what good is it having functions that can operate on such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That support was [added in a commit that also added tests](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/57d82897). We can look at those tests to see how it was expected to be used:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[test]
fn refcell_unsized() {
    let cell: &RefCell<[i32]> = &RefCell::new([1, 2, 3]);
    {
        let b = &mut *cell.borrow_mut();
        b[0] = 4;
        b[2] = 5;
    }
    let comp: &mut [i32] = &mut [4, 2, 5];
    assert_eq!(&*cell.borrow(), comp);
}
```

You always need to have a constructor with a `Sized` bound as the compiler needs to know the amount of space to allocate on the stack. Once you have that, you can then coerce to a dynamically-sized type.

Comment: Is it possible to create a `RefCell<Any>`?  I've tried `RefCell::new(x) as RefCell<Any>`, however, I get an error saying `Sized` is not implemented for `Any`.  On the other hand, `Box::new(x) as Box<Any>` works just fine.  They seem to have similar `?Sized` restrictions.  What am I missing?  https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5af8c51ac91d162d999f&version=stable

Comment: @Matt an interesting question. I don't know the answer, but I'd encourage you to ask a new question, linking back to this question if you think it provides useful context.