# Is it possible to create a RefCell<Any>?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to create something of type `RefCell<Any>` in Rust?  I tried the following:

```
fn test2<T : Any>(x : T) -> RefCell<Any>{
    return RefCell::new(x) as RefCell<Any>
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `core::any::Any + 'static` [E0277]
<anon>:8 fn test2<T : Any>(x : T) -> RefCell<Any>{
```

The documentation for `RefCell` includes the following

```
pub struct RefCell<T> where T: ?Sized {
    // some fields omitted
}
```

Which leads me to believe (along with the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278766/why-is-sized-a-bound-for-certain-refcell-functions-but-not-all/35279362?noredirect=1#comment58318261_35279362) question) that such a thing is possible.  I also tried:

```
fn test1<T : Any>(x : T) -> Box<Any>{
    return Box::new(x) as Box<Any>
}
```

which works just fine.  Both `Box` and `RefCell` seem to have similar bounds, so I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I have this in a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3553a742d22bb95d0635&version=stable), if that is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Box` has the trait `std::ops::CoerceUnsized`, which allows to cast to `Box<Any>`. `RefCell` does not, so you can't.

Of course you can do this:

```
let x = RefCell::new( String::new() );
let x = &x as &RefCell<Any>;
```

So you can have a `RefCell<Any>`, but cannot construct one or coerce to one, only coerce references.

Answer (score 4):

`RefCell<Any>` is an unsized type; you can’t have an actual instance of an unsized type—how much stack space will it take? This is the same as the way in which you can’t return `Any` but must rather return `Box<Any>`; so also you can’t return `RefCell<Any>` but must return something like `Rc<RefCell<Any>>`. The likes of `RefCell<Box<Any>>` would work fine too, because a `RefCell` of a sized type is itself sized.

[Demonstration.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Aany%3A%3AAny%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Acell%3A%3ARefCell%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Arc%3A%3ARc%3B%0A%0Afn%20_test1%3CT%3A%20Any%3E%28x%3A%20T%29%20-%3E%20Box%3CAny%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Anew%28x%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20_test2%3CT%3A%20Any%3E%28x%3A%20T%29%20-%3E%20Rc%3CRefCell%3CAny%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Rc%3A%3Anew%28RefCell%3A%3Anew%28x%29%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20_test3%3CT%3A%20Any%3E%28x%3A%20T%29%20-%3E%20RefCell%3CBox%3CAny%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20RefCell%3A%3Anew%28Box%3A%3Anew%28x%29%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%7D&version=stable)